# Revoke access token once the Active session is terminated

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have intgerated wso2 Identity server with web portal, I have used OAuth authentication protocol. My requirement here is the access token which i retrieve after the successful authentication of the user to be revoked whenever the user decides to sign from device. I have integrated the termiante session API. But when the user clicks on the sign out of all devices, i'm triggering the terminate sessions API, the session is terminated successfully but the acess token which i have retrieved after the succesful authentication is still active. So How can i revoke the access token whenever the terminate session API is triggered. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: could you please mention the IS version?

Comment: Hi @Anuradha Karunarathna, I'm using IS with 5.10 version

Comment: Could you please mention the grant type that you use to get the oauth access token?